# running draw_polygon example in CGAl package in qt widget application

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, fedora, cgal

I try to following CGAL example in Qt widget application :
[example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2draw_polyhedron_8cpp-example.html#a2)

**main.ccp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
     MainWindow w;
 w.show();

        return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.ccp :**

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_polyhedron.h>
#include <fstream>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                       Polyhedron;

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open .off model"), "/home", tr("*.off"));

draw_poly(fileName);
 }

void MainWindow::draw_poly(QString fileName)
{
    QByteArray inBytes;
    const char *c;
     inBytes = fileName.toUtf8();
     c = inBytes.constData();
          std::ifstream input(c);

          if (!input || !(input >> mesh) || mesh.is_empty()) {
            std::cerr << "Not a valid off file." << std::endl;
         //   return 1;
          }

          input >> mesh;

          CGAL::draw(mesh);
}
```

when I ran it , it open dialog file to select .off file ,then it shows the following error:

```
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
```

any help ,please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Qt5 in daily business, and once considered CGAL as possible application base (without going further into this direction – not yet). Hence, this question made me curious.

I digged through the source code of CGAL on github and found out why the error message

```
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
```

occurs.

For this, I copied the relevant lines from [CGAL on github: Polyhedron/include/CGAL/draw_polyhedron.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polyhedron/include/CGAL/draw_polyhedron.h):

```
template<class Polyhedron, class ColorFunctor>
void draw(const Polyhedron& apoly,
          const char* title,
          bool nofill,
          const ColorFunctor& fcolor)
{  
#if defined(CGAL_TEST_SUITE)
  bool cgal_test_suite=true;
#else
  bool cgal_test_suite=false;
#endif

  if (!cgal_test_suite)
  {
    int argc=1;
    const char* argv[2]={"polyhedron_viewer","\0"};
    QApplication app(argc,const_cast<char**>(argv));
    SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, ColorFunctor>
      mainwindow(app.activeWindow(), apoly, title, nofill, fcolor);
    mainwindow.show();
    app.exec();
  }
}
```

Looking at this source code, it becomes obvious that `CGAL::draw()` is a small ful-featured Qt application in itself which establishs its own `QApplication` instance. The OP in turn tried to embed the `CGAL::draw()` in her/his own Qt application. It is not allowed to instance any derivates of `QCoreApplication` more than once (according to Qt doc. of [`QApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#details)):

> For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely **one** QApplication object, no matter whether the application has 0, 1, 2 or more windows at any given time.

(Emphasizing *not* mine.)

The CGAL doc. provides an (even shorter) example in [Polyhedron/draw_polyhedron.cpp](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2draw_polyhedron_8cpp-example.html#a2) to do this right:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_polyhedron.h>
#include <fstream>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                       Polyhedron;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Polyhedron P;
  std::ifstream in1((argc>1)?argv[1]:"data/cross.off");
  in1 >> P;
  CGAL::draw(P);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but there is no place to insert the `QFileDialog` at the right point.

Hence, `CGAL::draw()` is the wrong tool for what OP (probably) intends to do – embed CGAL polyhedron rendering into a Qt application. For this, it is necessary to use the things directly which are called somewhere inside of `CGAL::draw()`.

So, this is what seems appropriate to me:
making `SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, ColorFunctor>` a (main or child) widget in OPs Qt application.

I then walked a bit through the github repo to find out from which Qt widget `CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, ColorFunctor>` is actually derived from and found the following inheritance:

```
CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, ColorFunctor>
                           |
                           V
                 CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt
                           |
                           V
                   CGAL::QGLViewer
                           |
            +--------------+--------------+
            |                             |
            V                             V
      QOpenGLWidget               QOpenGLFunctions
```

So, `CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, ColorFunctor>` can be used like any `QWidget` (which involves making it the main window). It can become as well the center widget of a `QMainWindow` which gets a menu bar/tool bar with the `QAction` to open the `QFileDialog`, request a file path, open a file stream with this file path, and load a mesh from this file stream.

There is another minor detail where I stumbled over: The `CGAL::Polyhedron` has to be given to the `CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt` in the constructor and by const reference. To consider this, it's IMHO necessary (after successful loading of mesh) to construct the `CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt` instance by `new` and set/add it to parent widget afterwards. If this is not acceptable it's probably necessary to go even deeper and replace the `CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt` by an own implementation, using the source code of the former as “cheat-sheet”.

This is how such an application could look like:

```
#include <fstream>

#include <QtWidgets>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_polyhedron.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                       Polyhedron;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorPolyhedron fColor;
  Polyhedron mesh;
  // setup UI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QToolBar qToolbar;
  QAction qCmdLoad(QString::fromUtf8("Load File..."));
  qToolbar.addAction(&qCmdLoad);
  qWin.addToolBar(&qToolbar);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qCmdLoad, &QAction::triggered,
    [&qWin, &mesh, &fColor]() {
      const QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
        &qWin,
        QString::fromUtf8("Open .off model"),
        QString::fromUtf8("/home"),
        QString::fromUtf8("*.off"));
      if (filePath.isEmpty()) return;
      std::ifstream fIn(filePath.toUtf8().data());
      if (!(fIn >> mesh) || mesh.is_empty()) {
        qDebug() << "Loading of" << filePath << "failed!";
        return;
      }
      qWin.setCentralWidget(
        new CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorPolyhedron>(
          &qWin, mesh, "Basic Polyhedron Viewer", false, fColor));
      qWin.centralWidget()->show();
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Please, take this with a “grain of salt” – I've no CGAL at hand and couldn't compile/test the above code.

Comment: @n.m Did you try this sample code? Please, drop a comment if you cannot compile it. I did it carefully but, nevertheless, the compiler usually finds something to complain about.

Comment: unfortunately I still have a problem in using SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, ColorFunctor> ,it cannot be used as a type

Comment: qWin.setCentralWidget(
        new SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<Polyhedron, ColorFunctor>(
          qWin, mesh, "Basic Polyhedron Viewer", false, fColor));

Comment: @n.m I'm such a git! Would you, please, replace `ColorFunctor` by `CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorPolyhedron`. (I completely forgot that in the sample code, `ColorFunctor` is just a template parameter.)

Comment: @Sceff sorry for disturbance but I have a problem within the above code 
SimplePolyhedronViewerQ cannot be recognized , so I added "CGAL:: " before it 
but now the existing error is : no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt<CGAL::Polyhedron_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorPolyhedron>::SimplePolyhedronViewerQt(QMainWindow&, Polyhedron&, const char [24], bool, CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorPolyhedron&)’
              qWin, mesh, "Basic Polyhedron Viewer", false, fColor));

Comment: @n.m Yepp. As you said: missing `CGAL::` scope. Additionally, I forgot the `&` operator before `qWin`. (1st arg. must be `&qWin`.) I edited the answer.

Comment: excuse me I'm a newbie 
the app stopped working cause of :
 Signal received

 The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

 Signal name : SIGSEGV

 Signal meaning : Segmentation fault

Comment: @n.m Please, research about gdb, core dump, and stack trace. With gdb, you can get more details about the crash, i.e. in which function the segmentation fault occurred and what called what before.

Answer (score 0):

CGAL::draw() already handles the Qt stuff. You are trying to open a mainwindow in another one. Just call CGAL::draw(mesh) in your main() function without anything else and it will work.

EDIT: Which is exactly what Sheff explained in a much more detailed way.

Comment: it's working in main() 
but I want to use it in a GUI application so I want to use it in a method and call it

Comment: You cannot do that. You'll have to extract the significant code from Surface_mesh/include/CGAL/draw_surface_mesh.h and GraphicsView/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h and adapt it to your application.